# Proving a well-known inequality using S.O.S

Tags: inequality, summation, sum-of-squares-method

Using $AM-GM$ inequality, it is easy to show for $a,b,c>0$, $$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a} \ge 3.$$
However, I can't seem to find an [S.O.S form](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h80127) for $a,b,c$ 
$$f(a,b,c) = \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a} - 3 = \sum_{cyc}S_A(b-c)^2 \ge  0.$$

**Update:**

Please note that I'm looking for an S.O.S form for $a, b, c$, or a proof that there is no S.O.S form for $a, b, c$. Substituting other variables may help to solve the problem using the S.O.S method, but those are S.O.S forms for some other variables, not $a, b, c$.

Comment: is S.O.S. Sum of Squares?

Comment: @S.C.B. Yes, it is.

Comment: Not every nonnegative multivariate polynomial is a sum of squares.

Comment: @quasi in $\sum_{cyc}S_A(b-c)^2$, $S_A$ is not necessarily non-negative.

Comment: @SSepehr -- If you don't require $S_A$ to be always nonnegative, what use would it be in proving the required inequality?

Comment: @quasi S.O.S is the name for a well-known technique for proving inequalities. Try googling S.O.S  technique.

Comment: But if the coefficients multiplying the squares aren't nonnegative, you can't conclude that the sum is greater or equal to zero -- at least not that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52576/discussion-between-ssepehr-and-quasi).

Comment: Note that the S.O.S. does not make any assumptions on the sign of $a$, $b$, and $c$. Therefore the S.O.S. would be $\geq 0$ even if $f(a,b,c)<0$. This shows that you cannot prove you statement using this approach, not using the condition $a,b,c>0$. Try $f(u,v,w) = \left(\frac{u}{v}\right)^2+\left(\frac{v}{w}\right)^2+\left(\frac{w}{u}\right)^2-3$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $c=\min\{a,b,c\}$. Hence,
$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}-3=\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}-2+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}-\frac{b}{a}-1=\frac{(a-b)^2}{ab}+\frac{(c-a)(c-b)}{ac}\geq0$$

From here we can get a SOS form:
$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}-3=\frac{1}{6abc}\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2(3c+a-b)$$

Comment: Very nice. But where are the coefficients $S_A,S_B$?

Comment: @SSepehr  I fixed my post.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another SOS (Shortest)
$$ab^2+bc^2+ca^2-3abc={\frac {a \left( c-a \right) ^{2} \left({b}^{2}+ ac+cb \right) +b
 \left( 2\,ab+{c}^{2}-3\,ac \right) ^{2}}{4\,ab+ \left( c-a \right) ^
{2}}} \geqslant 0$$

Comment: It is a nice SOS.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a} \ge 3 \Leftrightarrow a^2c + b^2a + c^2b \ge 3abc$$
So we use these S.O.S forms:

- $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3abc = \frac{1}{2}(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2$.
- $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - a^2c - b^2a - c^2b = \frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}a^3 + a^3 + c^3-3a^2c = \frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc} (2a+c)(c-a)^2$.
  Hence, the S.O.S form would be 
  $$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a} - 3 = \sum_{cyc}\frac{3b+c-a}{6abc}(c-a)^2.$$

Comment: But the factors $3b+c-a$ are not necessity all non-negative, or am I overlooking something?

Comment: There are some conditions for $S_A,S_B,S_C$ which imply that the inequality holds. one of them is $S_A,S_B,S_C \ge 0$. but if you take $a\ge b\ge c$, saying that $S_A + 2S_B \ge 0$ and $S_C + 2S_B \ge 0$ is also enough.

Comment: Since the inequality is cyclic$,$ you must check when $a\leqslant b \leqslant c$ too!

Answer (score 1):

Because$:$ $$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a} -3=\frac{ab^2 +bc^2 +ca^2 -3abc}{abc}$$
It's enough to prove$:$ $$ab^2 +bc^2 +ca^2 -3abc \geqslant 0$$ by SOS.

Let $$\text{P}=2(a+b+c)\cdot (ab^2 +bc^2 +ca^2 -3abc)$$
We have$:$
$$\text{P}=a \left( a+2\,b \right)  \left( b-c \right) ^{2}+c \left( c+2\,a
 \right)  \left( a-b \right) ^{2}+b \left( b+2\,c \right)  \left( c-a
 \right) ^{2}$$
Let me explain the method$,$ let
$$\text{P}_{\text{sos}}=\sum \left( {\it QQ}_{{1}}{a}^{2}+{\it QQ}_{{4}}ab+{\it QQ}_{{5}}ac+{\it 
QQ}_{{2}}{b}^{2}+{\it QQ}_{{6}}bc+{\it QQ}_{{3}}{c}^{2} \right) 
 \left( a-b \right) ^{2}
$$
Get an identity give $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
 -{\it QQ}_{{1}}-{\it QQ}_{{2}}=0&\\2\,{\it QQ}_{{1}}-{\it QQ}_{
{4}}-{\it QQ}_{{6}}=0&\\2\,{\it QQ}_{{2}}-{\it QQ}_{{4}}-{\it QQ}_{{5}}+
2=0&\\2\,{\it QQ}_{{3}}+{\it QQ}_{{5}}+{\it QQ}_{{6}}-4=0&\\-{\it QQ}_{{1}
}-{\it QQ}_{{2}}-2\,{\it QQ}_{{3}}+2\,{\it QQ}_{{4}}+2=0  
 &
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Solve this with $Q_i \geqslant 0 ,(i=1..6)$ give us$:$ $$ \left\{ {\it QQ}_{{1}}=0,{\it QQ}_{{2}}=0,{\it QQ}_{{3}}=1,{\it QQ}_{
{4}}=0,{\it QQ}_{{5}}=2,{\it QQ}_{{6}}=0 \right\} $$

Take it into $\text{P}_{\text{sos}}$ give the SOS form.
By the same way$,$ we have$:$ $$\text{P}=\frac{1}{3} \sum (2ab-bc-ca)^2 +\sum 2ab(b-c)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a} - 3 = \frac{(a-b)^2}{(a+b)b} + \frac{(b-c)^2}{(a+b)c} + \frac{(c-a)^2b}{(a+b)ca}.$$

Comment: +1), Nice SOS expression.

Comment: @tthnew Your SOS is nice as well.

Comment: I found another, see now.

Comment: @tthnew Can you find a simple SOS by your tool: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3799517/proving-31%E2%88%92aa21%E2%88%92bb21%E2%88%92cc2%E2%89%A51abca2b2c2/3799773